# Changes in maxmind.com free GeoLite databases

Tags: geoip, maxmind

Maxmind.com had changed some fields and name scheme of their free cvs databases as of 01/06/2015. Furthermore the IPv6 database information had been split of and is provided separately now.

I would like to know, if

1. this happened also to the databases in mmdb format?
2. maxmind gave some info to developers prior changing this?

I'am running the github.com/AndreasBriese/ipLocator repo and was surprised of the changes (that posed the need to update the software yesterday)

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the GeoLite2 CSV format, it was an alpha pre-release until recently in order to get feedback on the format. This was clearly specified on [the download page](https://web.archive.org/web/20141005111821/http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/) as well as the [CSV spec page](https://web.archive.org/web/20140704010933/http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geoip2-csv-databases/).

The MMDB GeoIP2 databases have not changed as they have been production releases for well over a year. Similarly, the Legacy CSVs have not changed.

Comment: THX for explanation. I had used the GeoLite2 CSV the last year and had not been aware of the change until my code broke. Maybe others will also benefit from the information you shared here. THX again